# Choose random source for HTML5 video

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I am running the following code which changes the source of an html5 video as soon as the initial source ends. After the first video finishes, it runs the second, then third and eventually starts again from the beginning, resulting in an endless cycle.

```js
var myvid = document.getElementById('myvideo');
var myvids = [
  "http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4", 
  "http://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4"
  ];
var activeVideo = 0;

myvid.addEventListener('ended', function(e) {
  // update the active video index
  activeVideo = (++activeVideo) % myvids.length;

  // update the video source and play
  myvid.src = myvids[activeVideo];
  myvid.play();
});
```

```html
<video src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" id="myvideo" width="320" height="240" autoplay muted playsinline style="background:black">
</video>
```

Now my question is: How can I randomize which of the videos in the javascript code comes first? I would like it to randomly choose one from the list, whenever the code is executed the first time. After choosing a random starting point, it should go through the list in the normal order. It shouldn't make every video random, only the starting point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this: 
It will start on a random video of an array of videos, and it will be reproducing sequentially till end of array and start from beginning again.

```js
var vidElement = document.getElementById('myvideo');
var vidSources = [
  "http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4", 
  "http://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4"
  ];
var activeVideo = Math.floor((Math.random() * vidSources.length));
vidElement.src = vidSources[activeVideo];
vidElement.addEventListener('ended', function(e) {
  // update the active video index
  activeVideo = (++activeVideo) % vidSources.length;
  if(activeVideo === vidSources.length){
    activeVideo = 0;
  }

  // update the video source and play
  vidElement.src = vidSources[activeVideo];
  vidElement.play();
});
```

```html
<video src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" id="myvideo" width="320" height="240" autoplay muted playsinline style="background:black">
</video>
```

Comment: Perhaps I should have explained this better: I do not want it to go through the list in a random order. The order of videos in the list should stay the same. It should only randomly choose with which video to start. Like, it would randomly start with video nr. 7, then afterwards play video nr. 8, nr. 9 etc..

Comment: @JaschaGoltermann yes, in this example it just start from a random position of the videos, and when it finish it will go to the next position of the array. (Ex: if you have 5 videos it will start in a random position like 3 and it will reproduce in the order 3,4,5,1,2,...)

Answer (score 4):

You can try this :

```js
function getRandomIndex(max) {
  /* The function will return a random number between 0 and max - 1 */
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
}

function randomlyChooseVideo() {
  activeVideo = getRandomIndex(myvids.length);

  // update the video source and play
  myvid.src = myvids[activeVideo];
  myvid.play();
}

var myvid = document.getElementById('myvideo');
var myvids = [
  "http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4", 
  "http://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4"
  ];
/* The initial active video will radomly be choosen between 0 and videoArray length - 1 */
var activeVideo = getRandomIndex(myvids.length);

window.onload = function(e) {
  randomlyChooseVideo()
}

myvid.addEventListener('ended', function(e) {
  randomlyChooseVideo()
});
```

```html
<video src="" id="myvideo" width="320" height="240" autoplay muted playsinline style="background:black">
</video>
```

Comment: I only see an error message when I rund your code snipped: "message": "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null"

Comment: I edited it, the error is normal because i didn't add your html code :) I also add a function that will randomly choose the initial video after window loading :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use random function like this
so the code will be

```
var myvid = document.getElementById('myvideo');
var myvids = [
  "http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4", 
  "http://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4"
  ];
var activeVideo = 0;

myvid.addEventListener('ended', function(e) {
  // update the active video index
  activeVideo = (Math.floor[Math.random()*myvids.length]) % myvids.length;

  // update the video source and play
  myvid.src = myvids[activeVideo];
  myvid.play();
});
```

Comment: Perhaps I should have explained this better: I do not want it to go through the list in a random order. The order of videos in the list should stay the same. It should only randomly choose with which video to start. Like, it would randomly start with video nr. 7, then afterwards play video nr. 8, nr. 9 etc..

Comment: in simple way you can copy and append my function to end of your code and this will lead to run the code and haveing random starting video